# update only params passed to express/mongoosd

Tags: express, mongoose

I have an Express Mongoose API that I've put together. When I use the PUT endpoint, I have to pass all params with any fields that I change. If I just pass one, then all the other fields become blank.

For example, let's say I have a collection with the following:

firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  email: String,
  postedon: Date,
  comment: String,
  rate: Number

My PUT code looks like this:

```
.put(function(req, res){

  Guestbook.findById(req.params.id, function(err, guestbook){

    if(err)
      res.send(err);

    //UPDATE
    guestbook.firstname = req.body.firstname;
    guestbook.lastname = req.body.lastname;
    guestbook.email = req.body.email;
    guestbook.postedon = req.body.postedon;
    guestbook.comment = req.body.comment;
    guestbook.rate = req.body.rate;

    guestbook.save(function(err){

      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(guestbook);

    });

  });

})
```

If I only enter a new first-name, then my document updates with the new name and all the other fields are removed.

Is there a way to pass just one or two of the params when updating and only change those fields, without making the other blank?

Comment: You can try the same with the below logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the same with `Object.keys` and checking for `undefined` as below. So, you can pass only whatever changed and no need to pass other params.

```
.put(function(req, res){

  Guestbook.findById(req.params.id, function(err, guestbook){

    if(err)
      res.send(err);

    //UPDATE
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(prop) {
       if(typeof req.body[prop] !== 'undefined') {
          guestbook[prop] = req.body[prop];
       }
    });

    guestbook.save(function(err){

      if(err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(guestbook);

    });

  });

});
```